# How much health do you have at each level in Bastion?

Tags: bastion

Can't seem to find it anywhere!

Answer (score 19):

According to the PlayerUnits.xml file, your character starts off with 51 health, and then you receive +2 health for every level, up to level 10:

```
 Level | Health
----------------
   1   |   51
   2   |   53
   3   |   55
   4   |   57
   5   |   59
   6   |   61
   7   |   63
   8   |   65
   9   |   67
  10   |   69
```

Besides the health you receive for leveling up, you can also add an additional 10 health at any time by equipping the Squirt Cider spirit.

Comment: There's also at least one spirit that *reduces* health by 10 as well, but that might only be available in New Game+ and I can't remember its name or its positive effect. >.<

Comment: You're referring to Doomshine: +10% Critical Hit Chance & -10 Max Health.